PCB Power and Ground planes Setup
When designing a 2-layer PCB, I've read that ground planes are good to reduce noise and to provide a stable-ish ground reference when a board isn't connected to a chassis, ground etc.
If I need to route a bunch of power all over the place, is it best to have two ground planes for noise reduction, or is it alright if one side has a ground plane while the other has a power plane? Do power planes have a noise reducing effect, or is that just ground planes? If I only need to power a few components, should I just have two ground planes?

For HF, ground and power planes are identical in the ideal case. If you have "a bunch of power all over the place", have you considered a 4 layer board with solid ground and power on two layers and your routing on the remainder?

Possible duplicate of: Ground and power plane for this simple 2-layer PCB -- if not, could you explain in more detail how your concern differs from this or other references?

By HF you mean high frequency? How would this make ground and power planes identicle? A bunch is rather arbitrary, but any more than 2 layers would be wasted with my component density, the only reason it's 2 layers rather than 1 is to avoid using wire bridges.

HF would capacitively couple equally well to ground as Vcc in a PCB.

@TimWilliams The explanation there is extremely wordy, and doesn't really get to the point, but I take it as them saying that in this case there should be ground planes but no power.

In fact, the domain of EMC (electromagnetic compatibility), including PDN (power distribution network) analysis, signal quality, etc., is a vast, deep and interconnected foundation to electronics as we know it today; that the answer is merely "extremely wordy", and not book-length, I guess should be taken as a compliment? :) But yes, in short: pouring GND both sides, with via stitching, and adequate bypassing on all supplies, is the preferred 2-layer scheme.

@SteamRanger why not go for a four layer board? I can assure you that skimping on the PCB design will bite you on many jobs. The cost of 4-layer may be a bit more than 2-layer but, it's usually worth it until you develop a feel for what can be achieved with 2-layer and how to track-it correctly.

You should describe the signal types that you have on the board, and what your interference concerns are.  Something like my signals are Low-level/low-frequency/high gain and I'm concerned about voltage accuracy and external pickup to my signals are fast/high frequency with edge times like [N] nS and I'm concerned about my pcb's emissions affecting neighbors or failing tests.  Include actual frequency and time values and/or ranges.

There is a excellent talk given by Rick Hartley How to Achieve Proper Grounding regarding PCB routing, ground and power planes, stack ups, and EMI. It is well worth your time if you haven't seen it. It will answer many of your questions.
